Subscription upgrade vs expire - distinguish SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED notifications
There are two conflicting cases when Google sends SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED notification

subscription is expired, entitlements should be romoved
subscription is superseded by another, entitlements should be changed

In the second case Google sends two notifications:

SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED for previous subscription
SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED for the new one

Both notifications contain different purchaseTokens
Using the token from SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED I can get the new subscription and see that it refers to the previous purchaseToken, this shows that this particular purchase is an upgrade or a downgrade
But if I get subscription details by the token from SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED there are no details telling wether this is a "Final Expiration" or it is just a "Supersession"
Both notification may come in different order, and we may receive SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED before SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED is processed and we have to distinguish which action should be applied - removing entitlements, or ignoring and waiting for SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED
How should I check whether a particular SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED is a "Final Expiration" or it is just a "Supersession"?
